# How to design a gridview in gl

Tags: android, opengl-es, view

Ok I couldn't figure out how to word this in a decent fashion so I will propose it as a "How would you?".

I have an app that connects to a service that interfaces all of the data to one main activity. The activity is split in two by a sliding drawer. To top part of the drawered activity is just some buttons that help set up the app and act as a main menu to quickly get anywhere.

The bottom (revealed by drawer click) is the heart of the app, a gl window that display 9 benches that hold 6 widgets each. The widgets display useful data and must be able to be moved around freely and longclicked to open an options menu.

This is where my problem is, I was using a gridview to hold the widgets, but now that I'm using GL for the benches and the touch listener, I don't know how to overlay the gridview to the benches and still keep the touch movement alive for the the GL window AND still be able to interact with the gridview.

This leaves me asking for anyone's oppinion on how to go about this. At this point the only option I have is to figure out how to make ALL of the widgets (even though some may even be a bar graph) in gl. I would rather not do that since gl and I don't work nicely with one another. But I really can't figure out how to integrate these features and still make it functional. Any Ideas?!

CONVERTING GRIDVIEW TO BITMAP

This method is in my extension of gridview (WorkBench). Essentially what I'm doing is walking through an array of gridviews collecting the bitmaps of each view and then setting the bitmap as the texture to the panels.

The toBitmap from the WorkBench class

```
public Bitmap toBitmap() {
    int x = getWidth();
    int y = getHeight();
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(x, y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(b);
    draw(canvas);
    return b;
}
```

And here is where I init the WorkBenches

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
for (int i = 0; i < mWB.length; i++) {
    mWB[i] = mBoundService.createBench(ARMHomescreen.this, i+"");
    mWB[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Whats happening is the WorkBenches dimensions are never being set, regardless of whether I use a LayoutParam or set the size in the toBitmap method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conventional layout to design your widgets. If your widgets can be at all complex this is certainly the best thing to do.

But OpenGL can't do anything with Android layouts, so what you do for each widget is :

1. Inflate a private View containing your widget layout.
2. Fill the your widget with the values to be displayed (text etc)
3. The crucial bit: draw your widget to a private Bitmap (using `View.draw(Canvas)`).
4. Convert your bitmap to a GL texture for GL rendering

Obviously you only need to do #1 once, and #2 and #3 every time your widget changes some aspect of its display.

I have used this approach for an Augmented Reality app which has complex layouts floating on a camera preview and it works very well indeed.

**ADDED LATER:**

Here is a screen capture of my OpenGL overlay on a camera preview background:

[image]

The overlay items are drawn to private bitmaps using conventional layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/ar_regus_frame">

<TextView    
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="1" 
/>

<TextView    
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bkgnd_red_field"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

With this technique you enjoy the best of both worlds... you get to use Android's amazingly powerful layout system to design complex UI elements, and render them with the speed and fluidity of hardware-accelerated OpenGL.

**ADDED 3rd FEB 2011 11:56am ish**

Here is how you draw a view to a private bitmap:

```
// Inflate the view
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.whatever, null);

// HERE YOU SET ALL YOUR VIEW AND CHILD VIEW PROPERTIES, TEXT ETC
// eg view.findViewById(R.id.foo).setSomeProperty(etc);

// Now we set the desired pixel size of our view. This is something the framework
// would normally do for you, as a result of the view being attached to the
// Window's view hierarchy. Since *this* view is *not* attached to the Window, we
// have to do it manually
// NB: omitted DP to pixels conversion for clarity
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(160, 160))); 
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width  = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
view.layout(0, 0, width, height);

// Finally we draw our view to a private bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);

// The bitmap can now be converted to a GL texture in the normal way.
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just creating a texture of then widget and attaching it to a plane, but I figured it would be to costly with widgets that change data multiple times a second. How expensive do you think it would be to create a bitmap of the gridview and changing the texture maybe 20 times a second?

Comment: 54 little widgets which together occupy rather less than a typical screen... 20fps should be easily achievable. (Providing you don't need to call measure() and layout() each change). Can you add a screenshot of your widgets?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA I've updated my answer with a screen capture and some layout xml to sort of prove what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Reuben - Sorry for the delay; this [the recently added image] is an older version of what I'm doing. Fairly simplistic right now but should get the point across. This is pre-GL. The user just touches a slot and different functionality happens based on what occupies a the touched grid location. The gauge widget that is displayed is updating about twenty times a second, other non-gauge widgets may be updated maybe once or twice a minute.

Comment: As for your example, it looks great and should work for me. I would just have to revert to only onTouch and calculate where everything is to figure out what to do with each touch.

Comment: For the gauge, I see little point in using 2D layout. It is presumably just a background image and a needle, yes?

Comment: For the most part, the dial is its own bitmap too, so it can rotate. just a flourish. What do you recommend then?

Comment: What does the dial look like? Your question suggested there were many widget types... if there's only 2 fundamental types that simplifies your life a lot. And neither gauge nor dial seem to require much in the way of layout, so I'd suggest doing those in pure GL. What is the issue re touch? How are these things supposed to respond to touch? You can handle onTouchEvent() in your GLSurfaceView quite easily, and the math to convert from Canvas pixels to OpenGL projection is seldom baffling...

Comment: The dial is the circle of white ticks in the gauge. There are going to be many types of widgets (graphs of all kinds and text displays) aside from the gauge widget, however I only have some of the gauge widgets written. As for touch and GL, this is my first time in gl. Granted it looks a hell of a lot easier in Android than it does in straight C of normal java, I'm still having issues with it. The conversion form canvas to projection for instance I am completely unaware of. I have just been quess-ti-mating conversions and such.

Comment: The touch commands are simple but there are a lot as well. For instance I need any given slot in the "Gridview" to be able to switch locations with another (I had that done in normal view) and add remove widgets from the view (also had this done). But I also need to slide from panel to panel, which can't be done using the normal views, which is the reason I switched to GL in the first place, aside from I wanted to learn it. :)

Comment: Well your gl code will have a glOrtho or something like that to set up the projection (i.e. the coordinate system)... a frequent setup for me is to have (0,0) in the centre of the screen, whereas the Canvas APIs have (0,0) in the top-left corner. You simply have to map your Canvas-based touch coordinates to the GL projection.

Comment: Btw, visiting a client tomorrow so likely to not be able to discuss this further for 20 or so hours... sorry. But look forward to resolving this after that.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with all this, I just have one last little issue, if you can bare with me. How do I get the current bitmap of my view? Right now I am creating a bitmap object and canvas and having the view draw into my canvas (which has worked before) But when ever I try to get the bitmap of the view when GLSurfaceView is on the screen, I only get a white square. I'm thinking it's because the view isn't in focus so it doesn't have anything to draw. I took the GLSV out of the picture and the view drew just fine, this helps my justification.

Comment: What do you mean by "the current bitmap of my view"? There's no such thing by default... views draw themselves in their draw() method, to a Canvas supplied by the framework (which will contain a bitmap). In my technique you don't use the framework's Canvas at all, i.e. your Views are never attached to your activity's view hierarchy. This means you have to size them yourself and explicitly draw() them to a private canvas. It's not hard to do at all... just paste some code into your original question and I'll show you what needs changing.

Comment: Ok I updated with the code segments I use for bitmap an how I set up the gridview. I'm pretty sure I'm getting the bitmap how you say.

Comment: (argh how I hate the comments system... updating my answer instead)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. The bitmap comes out fine now for my base views. Still not working with gl, but I think that's something to work on later.  Again, thank you.

Comment: No problem. If you want to elaborate on what "not working with gl" means I can probably talk you through that too.